# Using cognito as IDP for Spring authorization server

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-security, amazon-cognito, spring-authorization-server

I know normally Cognito itself is an authorization server actor in Oauth2 flow.
But as per my custom requirements I want to use spring authorization server with Cognito, basically:

- A client comes to oauth2/authorize endpoint with its client ID
- Redirects to login page and spring will know which client is trying a user to login.
- Client receives an auth code from spring after successful login (via
  Cognito, so auth code from spring, but login should be via cognito)
- Then sends a POST request to token endpoint of Spring to receive access/ID/refresh tokens from Cognito.
- All app clients will be taken from Cognito user pool.

I saw the JDBC example but can't really get it work with Cognito, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if it answers your question, but take a look at the [Federated Identity Sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples#federated-identity-sample) which may give you a starting point for federating to an external IdP.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't, but thx for helping tho.

Comment: AWS Cognito seems to have an authorization endpoint (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html) and supports OpenID Connect (OIDC). Therefore, I believe you can in fact configure the Federated Identity sample to use AWS Cognito as an `oauth2Login()` authentication provider (IdP). What makes you say the Federated Identity sample doesn't help you? All you would need to change is the yaml configuration.

Comment: But in this case, how can I configure to use all available app clients on cognito? Federated sample uses a single app client.

Comment: It's not 100% clear from your question what your use case is for the `client_id`, but if you need to pass a client_id through from SAS to AWS Cognito (or map client ids from one system to another), you can customize either the `OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver` or possibly the `AuthenticationEntryPoint` depending on your requirements. I can't quite visualize your flow since there are a few details missing from your question. If you want to update the question to be more specific about the end-to-end flow, that might help.

Answer (score 2):

I find in that regard the presentation "**[Want to authenticate using Amazon Cognito? Then use Spring Security!](https://www.slideshare.net/RyosukeUchitate/amazon-cognitospring-security)**", from **Ryosuke Uchitate** enlightening, regarding the integration of [Amazon Cognito](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/what-is-amazon-cognito.html) with Spring.

You can find his implementation at [`b1a9id/spring-security-with-cognito`](https://github.com/b1a9id/spring-security-with-cognito) (2018)

[image: Spring Security]

The general idea would be to provide a [`AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.html), using a `CognitoService`, with [`AutoWired` annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire):

```java
@Component
public class CustomCognitoAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private CognitoService cognitoService;

    @Override
    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        // Perform additional authentication checks if needed.
    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String username, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        // Call your CognitoService to authenticate the user with the provided credentials.
        return cognitoService.authenticate(username, password);
    }
}
```

---

For the Cognito service, you would need to add the [AWS Java SDK for Cognito Identity Provider](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-cognitoidp) to your project's dependencies. If you're using Maven, add the following to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-cognitoidp</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.454</version>
</dependency>
```

The service itself would require the appropriate AWS credentials, region, and Amazon Cognito configuration (client ID, client secret):

```java
@Service
public class CognitoService {

    @Value("${cognito.clientId}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${cognito.clientSecret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Value("${cognito.userPoolId}")
    private String userPoolId;

    private AWSCognitoIdentityProvider cognitoIdentityProvider;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // Initialize your Amazon Cognito Identity Provider with your AWS credentials.
        // Consider using a proper credential provider to avoid hardcoding credentials.
        AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY", "YOUR_AWS_SECRET_KEY");
        AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials);

        // Create the Amazon Cognito client.
        this.cognitoIdentityProvider = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
                .withRegion(Regions.YOUR_AWS_REGION)
                .build();
    }

    public UserDetails authenticate(String username, String password) {
        // Create the authentication request.
        AdminInitiateAuthRequest authRequest = new AdminInitiateAuthRequest()
                .withAuthFlow(AuthFlowType.ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH)
                .withClientId(clientId)
                .withUserPoolId(userPoolId)
                .withAuthParameters(authParameters(username, password));

        try {
            // Perform the authentication request.
            AdminInitiateAuthResult authResult = cognitoIdentityProvider.adminInitiateAuth(authRequest);

            // If the user is authenticated, return a UserDetails object.
            return new User(username, password, new ArrayList<>());
        } catch (NotAuthorizedException | UserNotFoundException e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid username or password", e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Error during authentication", e);
        }
    }

    private Map<String, String> authParameters(String username, String password) {
        Map<String, String> authParameters = new HashMap<>();
        authParameters.put("USERNAME", username);
        authParameters.put("PASSWORD", password);
        authParameters.put("SECRET_HASH", calculateSecretHash(clientId, clientSecret, username));

        return authParameters;
    }

    private String calculateSecretHash(String clientId, String clientSecret, String username) {
        try {
            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(clientSecret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "HmacSHA256");
            mac.init(secretKeySpec);

            String data = username + clientId;
            byte[] digest = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(digest);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Error calculating the secret hash", e);
        }
    }
}
```

---

You then *could* configure your Spring Security to use the custom authentication provider and set up the Authorization Server.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomCognitoAuthenticationProvider customCognitoAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration oAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authenticationProvider(customCognitoAuthenticationProvider)
            .apply(oAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/oauth2/authorize").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

BUT: as [documented here](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter):

> In [Spring Security 5.7.0-M2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/releases/tag/5.7.0-M2) (Feb. 2022) we deprecated the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, as we encourage users to move towards a component-based security configuration.
> In [Spring Security 5.4](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/releases/tag/5.4.0) (Sep. 2020) we introduced the ability to configure `HttpSecurity` by creating a `SecurityFilterChain` bean.

That means the more modern implementation would use a `SecurityFilterChain` bean:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .httpBasic(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

You need to pass the original parameter, like `.authenticationProvider(customCognitoAuthenticationProvider)` to the new `HttpSecurity http`, as illustrated in "[`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` Deprecated in Spring Boot](https://www.bezkoder.com/websecurityconfigureradapter-deprecated-spring-boot/)" or in "[Spring Security - How to Fix `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter Deprecated`](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/fix-websecurityconfigureradapter-deprecated)".

---

Then you configure your Spring Authorization Server ([`OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/2.0.x/api/index.html?org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/authserver/OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.html)) with your custom token store (using Amazon Cognito's access/ID/refresh tokens).

```java
@Configuration
public class OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private CustomTokenStore customTokenStore;

    public OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity> authorizationServer() {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity> authorizationServerConfigurer = new OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer<>();
        authorizationServerConfigurer
            .tokenStore(customTokenStore)
            .authorizationEndpoint()
            .baseUri("/oauth2/authorize");

        return authorizationServerConfigurer;
    }
}
```

That means implementing a custom [`TokenStore`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/TokenStore.html), which should be designed to handle the storage and retrieval of OAuth2 tokens (access tokens, ID tokens, and refresh tokens).

In your case: tokens issued by Amazon Cognito.

An in-memory one (not suitable for production) would start with:

```java
public class CustomTokenStore implements TokenStore {

    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, OAuth2AccessToken> accessTokenStore = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, OAuth2RefreshToken> refreshTokenStore = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken getAccessToken(OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        return accessTokenStore.values()
                .stream()
                .filter(token -> authentication.equals(token.getOAuth2Authentication()))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }
    ...
```

As noted in "[TokenStore in Spring Security 5.x after removal of Spring Security OAuth 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65904062/6309)", you need to check if this is compatible with the latests from Spring Security 5.X/6.0+.

---

From what I understand (but cannot durectly test), using your steps:

1. A client comes to the `/oauth2/authorize` endpoint with its client ID:

In `SecurityConfig.java`:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/cognito/callback", "/login**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login()
            .authorizationEndpoint()
                .authorizationRequestRepository(cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository())
                .baseUri("/oauth2/authorize")
                ...
}
```

As noted above, this should be done within a `SecurityFilterChain` if you are using Spring Security 5.X/6.x.

2. Redirects to the login page, and Spring will know which client is trying a user to log in:

In `application.yml`:

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          cognito:
            client-id: your-cognito-app-client-id
            client-secret: your-cognito-app-client-secret
            ...
        provider:
          cognito:
            issuer-uri: https://cognito-idp.your-aws-region.amazonaws.com/your-cognito-user-pool-id
```

3. Client receives an auth code from Spring after successful login (via Cognito, so auth code from Spring, but login should be via Cognito):

In `SecurityConfig.java`:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        ...
        .oauth2Login()
            ...
            .redirectionEndpoint()
                .baseUri("/cognito/callback")
                ...
}
```

That redirection endpoint configured in the SecurityConfig would be responsible for handling the callback from Amazon Cognito after a successful login. The auth code is actually received from Amazon Cognito, not from Spring.

Meaning:

- The user logs in via the Amazon Cognito login page.
- Upon successful login, Amazon Cognito sends the user back to the configured callback URL (e.g., `/cognito/callback`) along with an authorization code as a query parameter.
- Spring Security handles the request to the `/cognito/callback` endpoint and extracts the authorization code from the query parameter.

4. Then sends a POST request to the token endpoint of Spring to receive `access/ID/refresh` tokens from Cognito:

In `CognitoOAuth2LoginSuccessHandler.java`:

```java
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    OAuth2AuthenticationToken oAuth2Authentication = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication;

    // Retrieve the authorized client.
    OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = authorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient(oAuth2Authentication.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), oAuth2Authentication.getName());

    // Extract access token, ID token, and refresh token from the authorized client.
    OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = authorizedClient.getAccessToken();
    OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken = authorizedClient.getRefreshToken();
    String idToken = authorizedClient.getAdditionalParameters().get("id_token").toString();

    // Store tokens or use them as needed.

    // Redirect the user to the desired page after successful login.
    getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, "/success-page");
}
```

5. All app clients will be taken from the Cognito user pool:

In `CognitoOAuth2UserService.java`:

```java
@Service
public class CognitoOAuth2UserService implements OAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> {

    @Override
    public OAuth2User loadUser(OAuth2UserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
        // Extract user attributes from the OAuth2UserRequest.
        Map<String, Object> userAttributes = userRequest.getUserInfo().getAttributes();
        return new DefaultOAuth2User(Collections.singleton(userRequest.getClientRegistration().getProviderDetails().getUserInfoEndpoint().getUserNameAttributeName()), userAttributes, userRequest.getClientRegistration().getProviderDetails().getUserInfoEndpoint().getUserNameAttributeName());
    }
}
```

Regarding `OAuth2AuthorizationService`: there should be no need for a direct replacement of `OAuth2AuthorizationService`.
Spring Security's built-in support for OAuth2 should take care of managing the authorization code flow, including sending the authorization code to Amazon Cognito's token endpoint and exchanging it for access, ID, and refresh tokens.
The `CognitoOAuth2UserService` is responsible for loading user details from Amazon Cognito, while the `CognitoOAuth2LoginSuccessHandler` handles the successful authentication and provides access to the tokens.

Comment: Great, thx does this cover all the flow I have asked for?

Comment: Nonetheless, it's a good answer thx for it!

Comment: @SercanOzdemir Thank you. This was more a starting point to document what I have understood of the mechanism. I am still reading about [User Pool](https://blog.ippon.fr/2020/11/16/amazon-cognito-user-pool-ou-identity-pool-que-choisir/)

Comment: @SercanOzdemir The "[Amazon Cognito User Authentication in Spring Boot REST](https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/amazon-cognito-user-authentication-in-spring-boot-rest/)" is also a good read, as well as "[Securing REST API's with Amazon Cognito & Spring Boot - Part 1](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/securing-rest-apis-amazon-cognito-spring-boot-part-1-hamza-tariq)".

Comment: Totally, the resources you've shared are good. But @VonC basically Cognito is actually an authorization server, I have a custom use-case to use it as I've described in the question. I would simply use cognito instead of authorization server if I would use it only for authentication, but I have a really different use case please let me know if you find anything else or if you can improve the answer I'll give bounty to you asap :)

Comment: What's the replacement of OAuth2AuthorizationService here?

Comment: @SercanOzdemir If you use Spring Security "SecurityConfig" to delegate user authentication to Amazon Cognito and handle the OAuth2 authorization code flow, you would not need an OAuth2AuthorizationService anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253296/discussion-between-vonc-and-sercan-ozdemir).

Comment: This answer seems to use the deprecated spring-security-oauth2 project, not Spring Authorization Server.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg I suppose, since the article I initially based my answer was a few years old. I still have not managed to link all the pieces for that authentication workflow though.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd add some notes here on the OAuth architecture to aim for, and how I think of it, since your question had a couple of points that don't quite seem right. I can't help you on Spring AS specifics though.

**ROLES**

- Client: triggers user login via Spring AS
- Authorization Server: issues tokens to the client
- Identity Provider: one of many potential login methods

The client implements a code flow at the AS. The AS runs another code flow to the IDP. Chaining these systems together is very standard and should require only configuration, with zero code changes in the client.

**REGISTRATION**

- The client is registered only in Spring AS
- Spring AS is registered as a client in AWS Cognito
- AWS Cognito is registered as an authentication method (IDP) in Spring AS

**TOKENS ISSUED**

The client always receives tokens from the AS and not the IDP. The AS issues tokens that protect your business data. It enables you to issue whatever scopes and claims you need to lock down tokens.

**UPSTREAM TOKENS**

Clients and APIs should not usually need to deal with tokens from the IDP. There is sometimes an exception, eg also use AWS tokens to access the user's AWS resources.

If that is your requirement, aim to use embedded tokens. This means Spring AS issues IDP tokens as custom claims to AS tokens. This enables your APIs to continue to authorize correctly, while also being able to access AWS resources when needed.

Comment: There're actually 4 roles, aren't there ?